# web.config help - Forms authentication Issue

Tags: asp.net, authentication, web-config, forms-authentication

I developed an app in 4.0 (my 1st time) and I have only 2 pages in it. I deployed it and it is working fine.

I want the site to display all the pages with out asking for any userID and password at all. I have below code in my web.config

I think it is because I have below lines in my web.config file. But when I comment out these lines and deploy the code

```
  <authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/test.aspx" timeout="2880" />
  </authentication>
```

It is asking me for userid and password.

How can I fix this?? how can I make the app not ask for any userId and password at all. I added a index.html to the root and if I try to access it also I am getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Is your controller wrapped in `[Authenticate]`?

Comment: You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the credentials you supplied (access denied due to Access Control Lists). Ask the Web server's administrator to give you access to

Comment: Have you converted your project to a web application?

Answer (score 0):

When it's asking for user/password, is it the browser dialog box, or a form inside your app?

It seems based on your question that you're getting prompted for Windows authentication, not forms authentication. If that's the case, make sure you are allowing anonymous access to your app inside of IIS, and that there are no authentication requirements on a parent (website or virtual directory) above your application.

Comment: It is asking in a browser dialog box.

Comment: When I go to IIS and check the authentication the anonymous authentication is already enabled.

Comment: How about a parent? Is your app possibly a virtual directory underneath a website or another virtual directory, where the parent app's web.config has Windows authentication turned on?

Comment: No I checked and the windows authentication and forms authentication both are turned off.